# Postgres: Weighting full text search results by word order

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Is there a way to take into account the order of words when performing a full text search in postgres? In other words, is there a way to rank a result higher than other results if the work order is similar?

For example, if a full text column has the string *"See Jane Run"* in one row and *"Run See Jane"* in another row and a search of *"Hey See Jane Run Fast"* is performed, postgres currently appears to rank the two identically. How can a query be performed to prioritize based on word order?

I've tried plainto_tsquery and it appears to return no results unless all words match in a string which isn't what I need either. Thus, using plainto_tsquery to search *"Hey See Jane Run Fast"* would return no results because the words *Hey* and *Fast* aren't in the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging it appears phrase matching is a bit out of the scope for what fulltext RDBMS's can do. My solution was to implement lucene which can perform phrase matching.